# selecting data between a certain date range

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have fromdate and todate ..How will i get data that falls in this range ??

Comment: -1 for your rude "i don't want this " comment

Comment: Seriously, there are upvotes?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where date_column BETWEEN fromDate and toDate
```

Comment: Note that both `fromdate` and `todate` will be *inclusive* when using `BETWEEN`

Comment: @user415772 - so, what *do* you want?